# Will upvoting a users answers while running through recent tag questions ever result in serial voting?

Tags: discussion, serial-voting

Often, when I first get on SO, I'll run through the recent (maybe 10 to 20) [swing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swing) questions. When I do, if I see an answer that deserves an up-vote, I will vote it up accordingly. In many cases, there will be a single user that has answered a majority of these questions. So if I up-vote this user say, on all or most (let's just say 10) of this particular user's answers, will this ever result in serial voting?

Comment: Likely so, since the system can't judge a voter's intentions and obviously prefers to err on the side of caution.

Comment: @BoltClock So should I just avoid doing this? What do you think?

Comment: Having said that, you do upvote often so it's more likely that the system would treat it as part of your normal pattern. For example, if I suddenly upvoted 20 or 30 answers the system would probably treat them as suspicious.

Comment: Sometimes i open many question on problem, most of them partly help me  or deserve an upvote, i've voted like 15 to 20 answers in few minutes but system didn't say its serial upvoting ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The system might categorize this as serial upvoting and automatically reverse the votes, but it would be up to a moderator to take any further action on it after taking into account various other pieces of information. We don't release a lot of information on what we look at to determine whether there's cheating going on, because that would make it easier for cheaters to cover their tracks. Suffice it to say that it's a little more complicated that x% of votes.

Comment: Although moderators don't look at most cases of serial voting, unless specifically pointed out (though a flag, for example), do they?

Comment: @Dukeling Yes, that's right. We don't go around looking for voter fraud. Sometimes we do stumble upon it ourselves when we see something not quite right (like *terrible* questions and answers getting quick upvotes), but most of the time we're alerted to it through flags.

Comment: The system will auto-reverse the votes without intervention I thought?

Comment: @Yakk Yes, you're right. The system does auto-reverse serial upvoting without any moderator intervention in most cases. I edited my answer for clarification.

Comment: @peeskillet please note that a fundamental part of this accepted answer has changed.